# Object Explorer not showing all available databases in ssms

Tags: sql-server, ssms

In ssms I connect to a server. It displays two tables, `master` and `tempDB`.

Under the Available Databases dropdown I see `master`,`tempDB`, and `mydatabase`. only `tempDB` and `master` are visible in object explorer however.

Then I run

```
SELECT *
INTO newtable 
FROM tblMoveInMoveOutMonthSummary
```

which is a table in `mydatabase` but I get the error `CREATE TABLE permission denied in "mydatabase"`

so clearly I do not have sysadmin rights in `mydatabase` but I would still like the tables to show up in Object Explorer.

I can also run

```
select * from tblMoveInMoveOutMonthSummary
```

And it will return everything without error, it even autocompletes for me so I can see all the tables in the database in the query editor.

refreshing does not solve the problem.

Comment: but sql autocompletes for me and I can still do select * from tblMoveInMoveOutMonthSummary and it will return everything

Comment: Try disconnecting from the server and connect again!

Comment: I have refreshed several times

Comment: Does the user you are logged in to SSMS with have the correct permissions to see those tables?

Comment: I don't think so, I guess I'm perplexed by the fact that I can query those tables but can't view them in the object explorer. But I guess it really does come down to permissions in the end. I mean ssms even auto-completes the table names for me.

Answer (score 0):

The user login might denied to create table.

Please try at SSMS
Security -> Logins -> "login user" -> Properties -> Server Roles

and assign permission to the "login user"
[sample](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHotp.png)